# R how do I replace 0 with 1?

Tags: r, dataset

I have a data set N:

> [1] 10 13  9 12  5  9  3 13  5  2  4 20 17  1  0  8  5  1 13 10 24 17 7
> [24]  6 10 14 16  5  2 32 31 12  7  9  1  2  6  8  9 11  9  1  6  2 2  2
> [47]  3  3 41  7  2 15 11  5  3  7  5 12  4  4  7  7  5 10  3  2 10  8  5
> [70] 12 14 13  4 11  3  9 16 31  4 10  8 10  3 19 26 11  8 32  8 15  7  9
> [93] 51 25  3  7  5 10 16 15

I want to replace '0' with '1'.
I've try

```
M=N
if (N=0) M=N+1
```

but the result shows no difference with original N, what did I miss? How can I get the result I want?

Comment: Try `N[N==0]=1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `replace`:

```
replace(N, N == 0 , 1)
```

or `ifelse`:

```
ifelse(N == 0, 1, N)
```